# Permissions error in IE 8 but not Firefox 6.0.2?

Tags: permissions, client-object-model, anonymous-authentication

I am using the Javascript Client Object model to access some information from a list.  Below is the code I am using:

```
function getDeptInfo(id) {
        //var value = SP.ListOperation.Selection.selectListItem(id, bSelect);
        var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        this.website = ctx.get_web();
        this.listCollection = website.get_lists();
        this.oDeptList = listCollection.getByTitle('NavStructure');
        this.oDeptItem = oDeptList.getItemById(id);
        ctx.load(oDeptItem, 'Department_x003a_photoname', 'Department_x003a_phonenbr', 'Department_x003a_faxnumber', 'Department_x003a_email', 'Department_x003a_hours', 'Department_x003a_siteurl', 'Department_x003a_pictureurl', 'Department', 'ID');
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(Function.createDelegate(this, this.onSuccess), Function.createDelegate(this, this.onFail));
    }

function onSuccess(sender, args) {

        if (oDeptItem.get_item('Department') != null) {
            $('#department').html(oDeptItem.get_item('Department').get_lookupValue());
            $('#contact').html(oDeptItem.get_item('Department_x003a_photoname').get_lookupValue());

            //hours not in profile list? Hardcoding for now...
            //$('#hours').html(oDeptItem.get_item('Department_x003a_Main_x0020_Cont').get_lookupValue());
            $('#hours').html(oDeptItem.get_item('Department_x003a_hours').get_lookupValue());

            $('#phone').html(oDeptItem.get_item('Department_x003a_phonenbr').get_lookupValue());
            $('#fax').html(oDeptItem.get_item('Department_x003a_faxnumber').get_lookupValue());
            $('#email').html(oDeptItem.get_item('Department_x003a_email').get_lookupValue());
            $('#DeptLink').attr('href', oDeptItem.get_item('Department_x003a_siteurl').get_lookupValue());
            $('#deptHead').attr('src', oDeptItem.get_item('Department_x003a_pictureurl').get_lookupValue());
        }

    }
```

For some reason when I run this in Firefox as an anonymous user it works fine.  When I run it from IE as an anonymous user it errors out with:

> Error:The security validation for this page is invalid. Click Back in
>   your Web browser, refresh the page, and try your operation again.

Does anyone know why this would happen?  Any suggestions on how to resolve the error?

**UPDATE:**

I just tested this on a machine that is outside of our domain and everything works fine.  it only happens when internal machines run the code.  I have also since tested it with Safari and Chrome and neither of those throw errors - only IE.

Also, if I set "Web Page security validation" under General Settings to "Off" IE 8 stops throwing the error.  Any idea what could cause this?

Comment: Turning Web Page security validation off is risky. I will have one more go on this question: Try to set IE Security Settings for your site to Local Intranet or Trusted Site. And (just to be 100% sure) do you have any other custom code on this page?

Comment: 'Web Page security validation' is also quite common when you try to manipulate lookup fields markup from code.

Comment: Do you know which statement throws the exception? Is the onSuccess function executed in IE when the exception occurs?

Comment: try to attach a debugger in IE (F12 to get developer tools) and see exactly where the security validation occurs.

Comment: ever found and answer - I have a similar issue but then with SP2010 out of the box after a SP2007 upgrade - please see bottom of this http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/30fbf201-89b0-4b62-abc1-2d0d58c72f45

Answer (score 1):

If you provided only error in your code I would instantly write: Put [FormDigest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webcontrols.formdigest%28office.14%29.aspx) control inside your page.

```
<SharePoint:FormDigest ID="MyFormDigest" runat="server"/>
```

Quote from [Security Validation and Making Posts to Update Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms472879.aspx)

> For reasons of security, by default, Microsoft SharePoint Foundation
>   does not allow you to make posts from a Web application to modify the
>   contents of the database unless you include security validation on the
>   page making the request.

But as far as I see you are not making updates in your code. Take a shot and report back :)

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately.  As you mentioned I am not updating anything, so I don't think this would apply.